# possible replace Object.keys(myObj) with chain notation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Update**: if you are trying to do the same as me, you may be making the same mistake as I was, see my own answer below...

Here's the original question:

I'm learning React and I find the solution offered to map an object iteratively into jsx tags could be more intuitive.
Instead of

```
Object.keys(myObj).map(...)
```

I'd like to write something like:

```
myObj.keys.map(...)
```

I read an article [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/) by Richard Bovell, but that requires creating a new object and copy-pasted in to [codePen](https://codepen.io/fvila/pen/MBxQPe), but I don't see how I can mesh that in with declarations like

```
state={...}
```

or

```
myObject={...}
```

Comment: This is not idiomatic way to do this. Stick to `Object.key`. You can shorten it to `key` if it's too long to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `keys` method in the `Object` prototype and can use it accordingly.

```js
Object.prototype.keys = function(){
    return Object.keys(this);
}

var abc = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
abc.keys().map(elm => console.log(elm))
```

But this will change all the `Object` prototype affecting all the `objects` in the code.

---

Better solution would be just defining a keys function which does the same task for you, as mentioned in other answers as well.

```
function keys(object) {
  return Object.keys(object)
}

keys(myObject).map(...)
```

Comment: The prototype solution looks really elegant, what could be the side-effects of changing the other objects in the application? As long as you don't call .keys for those objects?

Comment: I don't think changing native prototypes is a good idea, though.

Comment: Since you cannot know often times what others (third parties) do with the native types and stuff.

Comment: @Francis *what could be the side-effects of changing the other objects in the application* - can the fact that this is a mortal sin be considered a side effect? Never ever modify prototypes for your own needs. The most obvious thing that can go wrong is that there's another smart guy who did same thing with this property, just because it seemed to be a good idea. And the second thing is that there's another guy who didn't expect that somebody messes up with prototypes at all, so his `if (obj.keys)` check will pass where it shouldn't.

Comment: @estus: _Mortal sin!_ Sounds interesting... ;-) OK I'll take your word for it. I'm a bit surprised that the effects should overflow over the scope of my own little component, when usually stuff not working as expected is due to it being out of scope.

Comment: @Francis Yes, the point is that modifying prototypes provides global side effects to entire execution scope. The only excuse that devs from early 10s had is that they didn't have module to import commonly used code like `key`, so they used built-in objects to provide it for entire app. Since this is React question, this clearly isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve `object.keys` doing the following:

```
const myObject = {
  someProp: 'test',
  someSecondProp: 'test2',
}

Object.defineProperty(
  myObject, 
  'keys', 
  {
    enumerable: false, 
    get: function() {
      return Object.keys(this) 
    },
  }
)

myObject.keys  // ['someProp', 'someSecondProp']
myObject.keys.map(...)
```

Defining this new property could be done in a function of your own making.
Though I wouldn't bother with it for just this type of short-hand, since I am content with using `Object.keys()`.
Alternatively you can define a `keys` function that pretty much just executes `Object.keys`.

```
function keys(object) {
  return Object.keys(object)
}

keys(myObject).map(...)
```

**Edit:**
As pointed out to me in the comments, you might as well fish out the `keys`-function from the Object-object.

```
const { keys } = Object
```

Comment: *Alternatively you can define a key function that pretty much just executes Object.keys* - this is redundant. `Object` and a lot of other static methods can be dereferenced. It's `const {key} = Object`.

Comment: Hmm, that could work as well. But since I don't know or test whether that behaves the same way, I didn't propose it like that.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, dereferenced static methods can be seen in a lot of well-written third-party libs, `Object` in particular. That's a legit way to save a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer from the guy who asked the question :**

Did I really need an object in the first place?

I was attached to the idea of using an object to represent a list because it offers a friendly handle to each individual item, such as `this.state.cities.london` in:

```
state={
  cities: {
    london:{name:"London", description: "Bla bla bla"}, 
    ny:{name:"New York", description: "Bla bla bla"}
    }
  others:...
}
selectedItem= state.cities
```

I thought I needed that handle so I would have a more friendly way of accessing each city than by its index number, like `this.state.cities[0]` in the case of an array:

```
state={
  cities: [
    {name:"London", description: "Bla bla bla"}, 
    {name:"New York", description: "Bla bla bla"}
    ],
   selectedCity:0,
  others:... }
```

This was was throwback from years of dynamic html and jQuery, where you need an id or at least at class name to manipulate anything.
In fact in 95% of cases you don't need to access directly, you handle the whole thing as a list:

```
ListOfItems=()=>{ 
  return(
      this.state.cities.map((value, i) => 
        <p  key={i} onClick={handleCityClick.bind(i, value)}}  >
          Click here for {value.name}
        </p>
      )
    )
  }
```

Used in render as:

```
  render() {
    const selectedCity=this.state.cities[this.state.selectedCity];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <this.ListOfItems />
        <h2>Detailed description of {selectedCity.name}:  </h2>
        <p>{selectedCity.description}</p>
      </div>
    );
   }
```

handleCityClick could be defined as:

```
handleCityClick=(i,val)=>  {this.setState({selectedCity: i}) }
```